# Select2 - can we set the dropdown menu to match the style of the rest of the page?

Tags: css, jquery-select2

I browsed the documentation for Select2 (https://select2.org) and searched their forum but haven’t found the answer - it may be that my limited experience is such that I’m not even asking the right question:

I am using the Materialize css (https://materializecss.com/) for my site’s styling. How can I get my Select2 dropdown to match the look of the rest of my page?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>   
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="body-custom">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
       <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="country" id="country">
             <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Country</option>
             <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
             <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
             <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
       </select>
    </div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#form {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.type label {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#proid {
    display: none;
}

.info {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.nav-custom {
    background-color: #333947;
}

.body-custom {
    background-color: #f0f7fa;
}

.title {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Codepen link:

https://codepen.io/Nola111/pen/yLNzeQp

Comment: Well, I guess you would have to write CSS to style it the way you want. Here is a couple examples of who have - [example 1](https://codepen.io/rpuga/pen/Baypwpr) and [example 2](https://www.codeseek.co/layzee/select2-material-design-theme-NRGmZG)

Comment: Oh wow, ok, I didn't realize it's such a manual process.  I thought there may be a way to match the style with a few lines of code.  Ok, in that case, I will have to reach out to one of my friends who knows CSS then!

Comment: Pretty hard to help - if I paste that code into my editor, nothing displays. If you can build a codepen as an example, it may help us help you.

Comment: @SeanDoherty absolutely.  I've never done codepen but now's better time than any other - working on it now.

Comment: @SeanDoherty here we go - https://codepen.io/Nola111/pen/yLNzeQp  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this is a work in progress as I'm sure you're going to ask me to style the dropdown next..!

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/zYGERzX

So first off, Select2 is forcing a 700px width on the select, which is making it wider than the materializecss inputs (which are always width: 100%). So we override it here. !important flag is needed unfortunately.

```
.select2 {
  width:100% !important;
}
```

Next up, the actual select field. As you know materializecss uses very minimal styling - just a border bottom in fact. So I looked at the base styles that are applied to all [materializecss input fields](https://materializecss.com/select.html), copied them into the codepen and then applied them to the following two elements. Select2 does real funky things, lots of nested divs (urgh) and it took a little while to figure out what the hell it is doing:

```
span.select2-selection.select2-selection--single,
span.select2-selection__rendered {
    // These are base materializecss input styles
    padding-left:0 !important;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
    outline: none;
    height: 3rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

As a final note - can I ask why you are using a 3rd party library for Selects? I don't know much about Select2, I did have a quick look at the docs and apparently they offer extended functionality to Select inputs. Materializecss can do the same without overriding styles and importing extra css.

If you are interested, I can show you a codepen that uses autocomplete to get similar functionality to your example. [Here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/zYGrXjJ)

Comment: Wow, Sean this is great!  First, no I won't ask you to style the dropdown, especially because of what you've brought up in your answer about being able to do this in Materialize.  To answer you question, I chose Select2 because I didn't know that Materialize had a dropdown where you could start typing and it would filter the list!  This is great news!  I am looking at your example now.  In the meantime, I am marking your answer since you definitely accomplished exactly what I was asking for. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: No problem. I know that framework inside out so let me know if anything about the autocomplete doesn't make sense. Essentially we set the min characters to 0 (minLength), which automatically brings up all options on focus - normally, on a traditional autocomplete we'd wait for the user to type at least one or 2 characters before bringing up the options. There is also an added check to see if what is typed exists, and if it doesn't, we delete the letter. This was a solution to another problem so you may want to leave that part out.